# Remover números ímpares de uma pilha

Tags: c, algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados, stack

Em C como se faz para remover apenas os números ímpares de uma pilha? Eu estava pensando em remover item a item e passar para um vetor, porém o tamanho da pilha não é dado.

Comment: Inclua o que você já tentou fazer, como você implementou sua estrutura de dados pilha, etc., desta forma fica mais claro sua dúvida, tornando mais fácil ajudá-lo.

Comment: Qual o código que você está usando, poderia postar uma parte pra gente ver?

Comment: Se o tamanho não é dado, então você precisa ou de uma lista encadeada ou de alguma outra estrutura de dados que cresça conforme a necessidade. Assumindo que isso seja um exercício, creio que o melhor é uma lista encadeada mesmo. Você está familiarizado com esse conceito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem uma pilha de números que vamos chamar de A.

O objetivo é tirar todos os números ímpares desta pilha. Como trata-se de uma pilha, não há como percorrer os elementos sem necessariamente destruí-los (caso contrário não seria uma pilha).

Então o que você faz é mais ou menos o que está no seguinte algoritmo:

```
B = nova pilha;

while (A não está vazia) {
    int t = remove elemento do topo de A;
    if (t % 2 == 0) {
        empilha t em B;
    }
}

while (B não está vazia) {
    int t = remove elemento do topo de B;
    empilha t em A;
}

apaga B;
```

Desta forma, você vai movendo os elementos de A para B e filtrando os ímpares. Na pilha B eles ficarão na ordem inversa. Quando terminar você faz o movimento contrário, e eles ficarão a ordem correta na pilha A, que também era a pilha original. O resultado é que a pilha A terá os elementos ímpares removidos.